# Como gravar um enum no banco de dados com JPA e postman

Tags: java, json, enums, postman

Estou criando um cadastro de produtos, e quando passo pelo Postman o JSON de meu produto para ser gravado, o seu tipo está sendo salvo como NULL.

Os tipos dos produtos são um enum, vou colocar abaixo o código que tentei utilizar para gravar os tipos. Estou fazendo algo de errado? Devo passar o JSON de outra forma? Agradeço pela ajuda

Código do Enum :

```
public enum TipoProduto {

    INFORMATICA(1, "informatica"), ELETRONICOS(2, "eletronicos"), CAMA(3, "cama"), MESA(4, "mesa"), BANHO(5, "banho"), CALCADOS(6, "calcados");


    private String descricao;
    private Integer codigo;

    private TipoProduto(Integer codigo, String descricao) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
}
```

Forma como estou tentando passar o JSON no POSTMAN:

```
{
    "nome": "Notebook",
    "TipoProduto": 1,
    "valor": 1300.00,
    "cor": "Cinza Fosco",
    "especificacoes": "8GB RAM, i7, 256GB"
}
```

Comment: Como o JSON é parseado? Como o objeto é persistido no banco?

Comment: Então, para persistir eu simplemente chamo o entity manager e dou um persist no produto.

No Produto Resource eu faço o seguinte: 

 @POST
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response adiciona(Produto produto) {
  produtoDao.adiciona(produto);
  URI uri = URI.create("/produto/" + produto.getId());
  return Response.created(uri).build();
  
 }

Comment: Vc já debugou o programa no resource, antes de persistir? O enum vem preenchido corretamente?

Comment: Então, fiz o debug agora, e ele está sendo preenchido como null :/

Comment: posta o mapeamento da entidade que possui  o enum TipoProduto

Answer (score 0):

Oi

Tenta passar o JSON assim

```
{
    "nome": "Notebook",
    "TipoProduto": "INFORMATICA",
    "valor": 1300.00,
    "cor": "Cinza Fosco",
    "especificacoes": "8GB RAM, i7, 256GB"
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas ainda assim não deu certo :/

Comment: Cara o enum não passa preenchido nem por reza

Comment: Como está o mapeamento na entidade JPA que usa o enum?

Comment: @Column(nullable = false)
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 private TipoProduto tipo;

Comment: Como só esse null tava me quebrando eu monto a tabela permitindo null, mas não é o certo devido a regra que eu tento aplicar

Comment: To dessesperado já, é só o enum que passa vazio, tudo passa corretamente

Comment: usando "INFORMATICA" você tentou debugar o serviço? está vindo nulo ainda quando chega no método adiciona? Porque para mim se você fizer TipoProduto.valueOf("INFORMATICA") dá certo

Comment: André consegui descobrir o problema, pelo menos eu echo, meu atributo chama tipo, quanto troquei ele e todo o resto para tipoProduto tudo funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado por me ajudar aqui!